# jQuery.validate cannot valid a nested form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

When I use the funciton `$('#frmPartialBusinessProfile').valid()` I am unable to find the form.  However, if I remove the upper form `frmMain` I am then able to find the control.  How do I find the control `frmPartialBusinessProfile` when it's nested in a form?

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@model Reverberate.BLL.Model.Form.Application.BusinessOnboardingModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Business Onboarding";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<style>
    .wide {
        width: 95%;
    }

    .field-validation-error {
        color: red;
    }
</style>

<form asp-action="Add" asp-controller="MyController"
      id="frmMain"
      name="frmMain"
      method="post"
      data-ajax="true"
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      data-ajax-success="onAddMainSuccess">
    <!-- Wizard -->
    @(Html.Kendo().Wizard()
        .Name("wizard")
        .Events(ev => ev.Select("onSelect"))
        .Events(ev => ev.Done("onDone"))
        .LoadOnDemand(true)
        .ReloadOnSelect(false)
        .Steps(s =>
        {
            s.Add<Reverberate.BLL.Model.Form.Application.BusinessOnboardingModel>()
            .Title("Business Profile")
            .ContentUrl(Url.Action("_BusinessProfile", "Onboard"))
            .Buttons(b =>
            {
                b.Next().Text("Next");
            });

            s.Add<Reverberate.BLL.Model.Form.Application.BusinessOnboardingModel>()
            .Title("Business Financial")
            .ContentUrl(Url.Action("_BusinessFinancial", "Onboard", Model))
            .Buttons(b =>
            {
                b.Previous().Text("Back");
                b.Next().Text("Next");
            });
            s.Add<Reverberate.BLL.Model.Form.Application.BusinessOnboardingModel>()
            .Title("Business Address")
            .ContentUrl(Url.Action("_BusinessAddress", "Onboard", Model))
            .Buttons(b =>
            {
                b.Previous().Text("Back");
                b.Done().Text("Submit");
            });
        })
    )
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dataPartial1;
    var dataPartial2;
    var currentStep;

    function onSelect(e) {


        var form, contentUrl;

        alert(e.step.options.index);
        alert(currentStep);
        if (e.step.options.index < currentStep) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
            alert('check');
            if (e.step.options.index == 1) {
                form = $('form[name="frmPartialBusinessProfile"]');
                dataPartial1 = form.serialize();
                contentUrl = '@Url.Action("_BusinessFinancial", "Onboard",Model)';
            }
            else if (e.step.options.index == 2) {
                alert('here')
                form = $('#frmPartial2');
                dataLesions = form.serialize();
                contentUrl = '@Url.Action("_BusinessAddress", "Onboard",Model)';
            }
            if (!form.valid()) {
                alert('not valid');
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            else {
                alert('valid');
                e.step.options.contentUrl = contentUrl;
            }
            alert('done');
        }

        alert(currentStep);
        currentStep = e.step.options.index;
    }

    function onNextStep(e) {
        if (e.step.options.index == 2) {
            openDoc();
        }
    }

    function onDone(e) {

        var form = $('#frmMain');

        if (form.valid()) {
            form.submit();
        }

    }

    var onAddMainSuccess = function (result) {

        if (result.error) {
            alert(result.error);
        }
    };


</script>
```

[image: Found now that i removed the upper form]

Comment: Instead of using traditional form submission, you could use JavaScript (or jQuery) to gather the input data from all the necessary fields across your "nested" forms and submit them via AJAX. This approach allows you to bypass the limitation by manually controlling the data gathering and submission process.

Comment: Form elements are not meant to be nested.